# Computation of the groups $K(BU \times \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(BU \times \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology

Let $U$ denote the limiting group of the chain $U(1) \to U(2) \to U(3) \to \cdots$

I wish to compute the group $K^{-1}\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}(BU \times \mathbb{Z})$. For this, we have the long exact sequence

$\cdots \to K^{-1}(M) \to H^{odd}(M;\mathbb{C}) \to K^{-1}\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}(M) \to K(M) \xrightarrow{ch \otimes \mathbb{C}} H^{even}(M;\mathbb{C}) \to \cdots$ .

It therefore helps to know the groups $K^{\pm 1}(BU \times \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(BU \times \mathbb{Z};\mathbb{C})$.

However I am unable to compute these groups. Could anyone please suggest some references where these groups may have been explicitly computed ? Or may be some hints as to how I may proceed ? Thanks so much !

Comment: $H^\ast(BU;\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z[c_1,c_2,\dots]$ is given by the Chern classes. A great place to learn about this is Milnor and Stasheff's _Characteristic Classes_. I should know something about $K^\ast(BU)$ off the top of my head, but I don't. But googling "K-theory of BU" leads to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space_for_U(n)), which calculates both your groups in section 3 and 4 respectively, referring to Adams' _Stable Homotopy and Generalized Homology_ for the $K$-theory computation. I'm still confused by the notation $K^n\mathbb C  / \mathbb Z$...

Comment: Ah, and as wikipedia notes, since $BU$ has even cells, its odd-dimensional $K$-theory vanishes.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks so much ! This indeed is helpful and gives me a very useful starting point. Regarding the notation : Given any generalised cohomology theory, one can do a 'change of coefficients' by smashing with appropriate Moore spectra. See for example, section 3.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01289.pdf
Can you elaborate your comment that since BU has only even cells, its odd K-theory vanishes ? I understand that BU has even cells only, but didn't understand the reasoning. You probably meant that odd-cohomology vanishes ?

Comment: The odd cohomology vanishes, and then since $KU_\ast$ is also concentrated in even degrees the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence collapses (everything is in even bidegree so there is no room for differentials) -- then since everything is in even bidegree, it's in even total degree, so the $K$-theory is also concentrated in even degrees.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks again ! Actually I haven't studied AHSS so far. Can you suggest a good reference ? 
Sorry to bother you so much, actually my knowledge of this stuff is rather weak. I feel confused as to how K-theory behaves with respect to limits/co-limits. The wikipedia page gives K(BU(n)), but I don't know how to deduce K(BU) from there. Can you suggest what material I should study for this ?

Comment: I feel like anything I know about this stuff I learned through some weird osmosis at some point, but I think the Adams book mentioned above might be a good resource. Just try not to get too hung up on whatever point-set formalism he's using.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks so much ! I will read the Adams book :-)

Comment: Regarding limits and colimits, recall that $K^\ast (X) = \pi_{-\ast }F(X,KU)$ where $F$ means the mapping spectrum. As a hom-functor, it carries colimits to limits in the first variable. So $F(\varinjlim BU(n), KU) = \varprojlim F(BU(n),K)$, where this is a homotopy limit of spectra i.e. a limit in the $\infty$-category of spectra. This means $K^\ast(BU) = \varprojlim K^\ast(BU)$, modulo checking that a $\varprojlim^1$ term vanishes. [The story of $\varprojlim^1$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences) is cute and not too bad, but it's sometimes annoying.

Comment: Yes Adams book is going to be one of the best places to learn this. Be warned: his book is written in reverse order of how one learning the subject should read it. You should read what he has to say about the AH spectral sequence (I think in the third part of the book), and then look at his computations of complex oriented cohomology using it (K-theory is complex oriented). This will be the second part of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you just have $K^n(\mathbb{Z}\times BU)=\text{Map}(\mathbb{Z},K^n(BU))$, so you can work with $K^*(BU)$, which is technically more convenient.  In particular, this is the inverse limit of the rings $K^*(BU(n))$.  If $V$ is a complex vector bundle of dimension $n$ over a base space $X$, we can consider the polynomial $g_V(u)=\sum_{k=0}^n[\lambda^k(V)]u^{n-k}\in K^0(X)[u]$.  We can then define $c^{KU}_k(V)\in K^0(X)$ to be the coefficient of $t^{n-k}$ in $g_V(t-1)$.  By considering the universal case, we get classes $c^{KU}_0=1,c^{KU}_1,\dotsc,c^{KU}_n\in K^0(BU(n))$.  It is a standard fact that $K^0(BU(n))=\mathbb{Z}[[c^{KU}_1,\dotsc,c^{KU}_n]]$, with $c^{KU}_n$ mapping to zero in $K^0(BU(n-1))$.  One way to prove this is to use the general framework of complex orientable cohomology theories.  Another is to use the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, which is in (even,even) bidegrees and so collapses.  By passing to the limit we get
$$ K^0(BU) = \mathbb{Z}[[c^{KU}_1,c^{KU}_2,c^{KU}_3,\dotsc]]. $$
We also have
$$ H^*(BU) = \mathbb{Z}[[c^{H}_1,c^{H}_2,c^{H}_3,\dotsc]], $$
with $c_k^H\in H^{2k}(BU)$ being the Chern classes in ordinary cohomology.